# Declare Foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have these database

```
  === Invoices ===
   id
   status
   description

   === Invoice Items ===
   id
   invoice_id (FK)
   item_name
   description
```

To make this table I have made this MySQL command

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nt_invoices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nt_invoice_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `invoice_id` (`invoice_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;
```

My problem is that I want to declare a foreign key in the `invoice_items` table and to make the `invoice_id` the foreign key of `invoices` table id. So how to write that command?  Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `innodb` engine type for using foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nt_invoice_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL references nt_invoices(id)
  `item_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `invoice_id` (`invoice_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

OR if you want to use cascaded update delete:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nt_invoice_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `invoice_id` (`invoice_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES  nt_invoices(id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
   ON UPDATE CASCADE,

) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 2):

MyISAM does not support foreign keys. You need to use InnoDB (which is a better choice in all aspects anyway). Then it's just like in any other SQL dialect:

```
`invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL references nt_invoices(id),
```

P.S. Also, **always** use utf8 encoding **everywhere**. It will bite you in the ass if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use ALTER command to declare FOREIGN KEY as follows:

```
Alter table table_name add foreign key(column_name)
    references other_table_name(column);
```